# How to get Identity id of the last row inserted in table in Magento 2

Tags: database, magento-2.1

I'm trying to insert a row in a table using following code inside controller.

```
protected $_objectManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
) 
{
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    parent::__construct($context);    
}

public function execute()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $model = $this->_objectManager->create('<<Company Name>>\<<Module Name>>\Model\XYZ');
    $model->setData('name', $post["name"]);
    $model->setData('customer_id', $post["customer_id"]);
    $model->setData('customer_is_guest', $post["customer_is_guest"]);
    $model->setData('testCol', $post["test_col"]);

    $model->save();
}
```

Above code works and row gets inserted into the table, is there a way to get the id (identity id) of the row inserted above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$model->getId();
```

if you plan to use it right after you call `save`.

Side note...please don't use object manager directly in your code.
Make your class look like this :

```
protected $modelFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \<<Company Name>>\<<Module Name>>\Model\XYZFactory $modelFactory
) 
{
    $this->modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);    
}

public function execute()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $model = $this->modelFactory->create();
    $model->setData('name', $post["name"]);
    $model->setData('customer_id', $post["customer_id"]);
    $model->setData('customer_is_guest', $post["customer_is_guest"]);
    $model->setData('testCol', $post["test_col"]);

    $model->save();
}
```

Comment: $model->save() is depricated.
It's recommended to save with the repository->save($model) or resource_model->save($model). But resource model returns itself in save method. So how could I get the primary key in this case?

Comment: in a similar way you will call `$repository->save($model)` and then get `$model->getId()`