# How to get Identity of recently inserted for Resource Save *(Magento 2.3.5)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, resource-model, repository

[The answer linked here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150424/how-to-get-identity-id-of-the-last-row-inserted-in-table-in-magento-2) mentioned (in the comments more specifically) that I am supposed to be able to get the Id from the repository/resource), it also more importantly confirmed that `$model->save()` is deprecated, and Repository to be used:

I implemented a Repository before this, and already had a working `insert/update` into the database.

The save() function is for a Repository implementation:

(Data for the Interface):

```
`order_history_id PRIMARY KEY`
`user_id`
`sales_order_id`

sales_order_id 19830 - The current sales order id
user_id 22           - A custom 'assigned user/sales/dispatch' ID
```

```
class AssignedOrderCommentHistoryRepository implements AssignedOrderCommentHistoryRepositoryInterface
    
    public function save(
        ..\AssignedOrderCommentHistoryInterface $user
    ) {

        $data = $user->getData();
        /** Remove primary id from array if this is a new row */
        if ($user->isNewRow()) {
            $data = $user->dataToArray();
        }
        /** **Model**\AssignedOrderCommentHistory $userModel **/
        $userModel = $this->assignedOrderCommentHistoryFactory->create()->setData($data);

        try {
           /** This is where I am saving (insert/update) successfully to database ... 
               How do I get the ID from here....  

               $inserted = $this->resource->save($userModel); 
               Returns type : '**Model\ResourceModel**\AssignedOrderCommentHistory' 
               which _does not have any getData()_ or there appears no 'primary id data returned'
           **/
           
           $this->resource->save($userModel);
}
/*** Try/catch trimmed */
        return $userModel->getDataModel();
```

I need the PRIMARY KEY `order_history_id` ID inserted for use in another data table, to store the related data.

Am I to implement my own `SELECT * from table LIMIT 1` statement to find the 'last inserted row'?  Would this even be reasonable to assume that I will get the correct ID with multiple inserts at the 'same time'?

I tried to look at some other examples, but most examples just show how to 'insert/update', which is what I already have correct.

Comment: did you ever find the solution to this problem. i have the same issue

Comment: Hi, I have looked at my code just now, I will try to write an answer regarding the issue soon.

Comment: @theSeeker  I apologise for the long answer, as this was months ago, I cannot really remove much as I feel most is relevant to getting you a working `save()` on Repositories.

Comment: @theSeeker  Did the answer I provided help you?

Comment: Hey  @CvRChameleon , i will have a look at your answer. i will also provide a quick solution that I  found to get the Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for the use of `save()` in a Repository, and I am trying to answer as @theSeeker also need a similar solution.

I created this around 7 months ago, and can't remember everything I have done, so the answer shows alot of code, but is relevant to a working repository, especially to `save()` when you have `custom non-default primary ID`.

## Relevant code

0. Your Resource (Database collection) should override the protected `_idFieldName` to the **custom column primary id**

```
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = DbHelper::FIELD_ORDERS_COMMENT_HISTORY_ORDER_HISTORY_ID;
```

1. `Save` function inside Repository class. (Rest of the Repository code truncated)

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function save(
        \Vendor\ModuleName\Api\Data\AssignedOrderCommentHistoryInterface $user
    ) {
        /* if (empty($user->getStoreId())) {
            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $user->setStoreId($storeId);
        } */

        /**
         * Not sure what these extensibleDataObjectConvertor is supposed to do, but I doubt it works
         * correctly, even sure in /Model/UserRepository and /Model/UserTypeRepository.
         * Same code taken from online resources.
         */
        // $data = $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter->toNestedArray(
        //     $user,
        //     [],
        //     \Vendor\ModuleName\Api\Data\AssignedOrderCommentHistoryInterface::class
        // );

        $data = $user->getData();
        /** Remove primary id from array if this is a new row */
        if ($user->isNewRow()) {
            $data = $user->dataToArray();
        }
        $userModel = $this->assignedOrderCommentHistoryFactory->create()->setData($data);

        try {
            $this->resource->save($userModel);
        } catch (AlreadyExistsException $exExist) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                __(
                    'Could not save the assigned details: %1',
                    $exExist->getMessage()
                )
            );
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__(
                'Could not save the assigned details: %1',
                $exception->getMessage()
            ));
        }
        return $userModel->getDataModel();
    }
```

2. Data Model - You can then create an Interface for your Data Model:

```
interface BaseExtensibleDataInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Return true if the object has data
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasData();

    /**
     * Return if this is a new row (no existing data)
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isNewRow();

    /**
     * Set that this is a new row (no existing data)
     * @return this
     */
    public function setIsNewRow();

    /**
     * Return if this is an update row (not a new row)
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isUpdateRow();

    /**
     * Set that this is an update row (not a new row)
     * @return this
     */
    public function setIsUpdateRow();

    /**
     * Get All data or data for a specific key when specified
     *
     * @param string $key If Empty will return all data
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData($key = "");

    /**
     * Convert object->getData() to Array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function dataToArray(bool $ignorePrimaryId = true);

    /**
     * Set data from array of data
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDataFromArray(array $data);

    /**
     * Set data from AbstractModel model
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDataFromModel(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model);
}
```

3. I then created an abstract object implementing the interface as I used it for several implementations.

> NOTE: I am truncating the class, just adding the code I feel is relevant to the issue.

```
abstract class AbstractApiInterfacedExtensibleObject
extends \Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractExtensibleObject
implements BaseExtensibleDataInterface
{
    protected $_isNewRow;

    /**
     * Return true if the object has data
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasData()
    {
        return !empty($this->getData());
    }

    /**
     * Return if this is a new row (no existing data)
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isNewRow()
    {
        return $this->_isNewRow;
    }

    /**
     * Set that this is a new row (no existing data)
     * @return this
     */
    public function setIsNewRow()
    {
        $this->_isNewRow = true;
    }

    /**
     * Return if this is an update row (not a new row)
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isUpdateRow()
    {
        return !$this->isNewRow();
    }

    /**
     * Set that this is an update row (not a new row)
     *
     * @return this
     */
    public function setIsUpdateRow()
    {
        $this->_isNewRow = false;
    }

    /**
     * Get All data or data for a specific key when specified
     *
     * @param string $key If Empty will return all data
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData($key = "")
    {
        if (!is_null($this->_data)) {
            if (!empty($key) && array_key_exists($key, $this->_data)) {
                return $this->_data[$key];
            }
            return $this->_data;
        }
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * Convert object->getData() to Array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function dataToArray(bool $ignorePrimaryId = true)
    {
        if ($ignorePrimaryId) {
            $data = $this->getData();
            if (array_key_exists(static::PRIMARY_ID, $data)) {
                unset($data[static::PRIMARY_ID]);
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return $this->getData();
    }

    /**
     * Set data from array of data
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return this
     */
    public function setDataFromArray(array $data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->_data[$key] = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set data from AbstractModel model
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model
     * @return this
     */
    public function setDataFromModel(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model)
    {
        return $this->setDataFromArray($model->getData());
    }
}
```

4. Then finally the **actual Data Model**

```
class AssignedOrderCommentHistoryDetail extends AbstractApiInterfacedExtensibleObject implements AssignedOrderCommentHistoryDetailInterface
{

    /**
     * Get PRIMARY_ID
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getPrimaryId()
    {
        return $this->_get(static::PRIMARY_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Set PRIMARY_ID
     * @param string $primaryId
     * @return \Vendor\ModuleName\Api\Data\AssignedOrderCommentHistoryDetailInterface
     */
    public function setPrimaryId($primaryId)
    {
        return $this->setData(static::PRIMARY_ID, $primaryId);
    }

    /**
     * Get RELATED_ORDER_HISTORY_ID
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getRelatedOrderHistoryId()
    {
        return $this->_get(static::RELATED_ORDER_HISTORY_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Set RELATED_ORDER_HISTORY_ID
     * @param string $relatedOrderHistoryId
     * @return \Vendor\ModuleName\Api\Data\AssignedOrderCommentHistoryDetailInterface
     */
    public function setRelatedOrderHistoryId($relatedOrderHistoryId)
    {
        return $this->setData(static::RELATED_ORDER_HISTORY_ID, $relatedOrderHistoryId);
    }

    /**
     * Get ASSIGNED_SALES_ORDER_HISTORY_COMMENT_ID
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getAssignedSalesOrderHistoryCommentId()
    {
        return $this->_get(static::ASSIGNED_SALES_ORDER_HISTORY_COMMENT_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Set ASSIGNED_SALES_ORDER_HISTORY_COMMENT_ID
     * @param string $commentId
     * @return \Vendor\ModuleName\Api\Data\AssignedOrderCommentHistoryDetailInterface
     */
    public function setAssignedSalesOrderHistoryCommentId($commentId)
    {
        return $this->setData(static::ASSIGNED_SALES_ORDER_HISTORY_COMMENT_ID, $commentId);
    }

    /**
     * Get ASSIGNED_USER_USER_ID
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getAssignedUserId()
    {
        return $this->_get(static::ASSIGNED_USER_USER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Set ASSIGNED_USER_USER_ID
     * @param string $userId
     * @return \Vendor\ModuleName\Api\Data\AssignedOrderCommentHistoryDetailInterface
     */
    public function setAssignedUserId($userId)
    {
        return $this->setData(static::ASSIGNED_USER_USER_ID, $userId);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve existing extension attributes object or create a new one.
     * @return \Vendor\ModuleName\Api\Data\AssignedOrderCommentHistoryDetailExtensionInterface|null
     */
    public function getExtensionAttributes()
    {
        return $this->_getExtensionAttributes();
    }

    /**
     * Set an extension attributes object.
     * @param \Vendor\ModuleName\Api\Data\AssignedOrderCommentHistoryDetailExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setExtensionAttributes(
        \Vendor\ModuleName\Api\Data\AssignedOrderCommentHistoryDetailExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
    ) {
        return $this->_setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
    }
```

### Explanation

Have a look at the `save()` function in the Repository.

> `$data = $user->getData();`

- The custom `getData()` filters information which I don't need and formats the array in the associative format Magento 2 expects for 'Data Models with Repositories'.

```
if ($user->isNewRow()) {
   $data = $user->dataToArray();
}
```

- I call `isNewRow()` to find if the row is new (you can use `setIsNewRow()` somewhere to set it as new if you can't determine automatically)
- The `dataToArray()` then removes the primary key when new row or not.

> `$userModel = $this->assignedOrderCommentHistoryFactory->create()->setData($data);`

- Create the Factory `AssignedOrderCommentHistoryFactory` of the Model `AssignedOrderCommentHistory` that you set in the constructor of the Repository (the name ends with Factory, with the same namespace as your Class, and **Magento 2 creates the class automatically when you run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` - for more information research further about Magento 2 Factories).**

> `$this->resource->save($userModel);`

- Then you can save to the Magento 2 resource, this will then *create a new row or update the model if it exists in the database*
  `$this->resource->save($userModel)`

`return $userModel->getDataModel();`

- Finally: Make sure you return *a different format Data Model* inside the `save()` function which Magento 2 expects.

## Summary

There is no summary, as this has been over 7 months ago, I cannot remember everything done here, I do remember the main things that had me struggling, and the explanation I gave above covers most.

## TLDR

- > Do I need a custom implementation for a Repository save when using a non-default primary ID name?
- Yes, absolutely yes!  Override the `Collection` primary id field, implement a custom `getData() and dataToArray()` to ensure the custom field is added / removed for new rows/update rows.